# Non Retina Ipad having blur issue when trying to get Thumbnail from Asset

Tags: uiimage, alassetslibrary, assets

I am having an application in which i need thumbnail of the image of asset i have selected from the gallery.

So wrote the following code for getting the thumbnail, it works fine in IPAD retina but the same thumbnail gets blur in IPAD non-retina.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.aspectRatioThumbnail scale:1.0 orientation:[[asset defaultRepresentation] orientation]];
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly do you display this image later?

One of possible reasons is that when you create image view using this image, you provide frame with one or few float values in XX.5 format.

For example:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.5, imgView.size.width, imgView.size.height);
```

In this case when you run such code on Retina display, you won't get blur since all values are basically multiplied by scale (which is equal to 2 for Retina), and 0.5*2=1.0 is valid position on screen, but for regular display with scale=1 you have y coordinate equal to 0.5 which might cause blur.